# Assembly has been tampered

Tags: c#, assemblies

I am trying to embed a third party library into my DLL. The DLL has been referenced and set not to copy local as well as added to the resources. I then do the following to load the DLL at during runtime.

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += (sender, args) =>
    {
        string resourceName = new AssemblyName(args.Name).Name + ".dll";
        string resource = Array.Find(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceNames(), element => element.EndsWith(resourceName));
        Assembly assembly;

        using (var stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(resource))
        {
            Byte[] assemblyData = new Byte[stream.Length];
            stream.Read(assemblyData, 0, assemblyData.Length);
            assembly = Assembly.Load(assemblyData);
            stream.Close();
        }

        return assembly;
    };
```

The assembly is returned and I can step further into the code but when instantiating a new object from the DLL's constructor I receive a TypeInitilizationException with an inner message saying "Assembly has been tampered".

Is there anyway around this or is my method of loading the DLL wrong?

**EDIT**

```
instance = new iConfServerDotNet();
```

also tried

```
System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo constructorInfo = typeof(iConfServerDotNet).GetConstructor(new Type[] { });

if (constructorInfo.DeclaringType.Name == "iConfServerDotNet")
{
    object o = constructorInfo.Invoke(new Object[] { }) as UserControl;
}
```

**EDIT 2**

The new code to get the type of class... and call it's contstructor. This still causes the same exception.

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += (sender, args) =>
    {
        string resourceName = new AssemblyName(args.Name).Name + ".dll";
        string resource = Array.Find(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceNames(), element => element.EndsWith(resourceName));
        Assembly assembly;

        using (var stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(resource))
        {
            Byte[] assemblyData = new Byte[stream.Length];
            stream.Read(assemblyData, 0, assemblyData.Length);
            assembly = Assembly.Load(assemblyData);
            stream.Close();
        }

        Type type = assembly.GetModule(resourceName).GetType("iConfServer.NET.iConfServerDotNet");

        //object instance = type.GetConstructors()[0].Invoke(null);
        object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

        return assembly;
    };
```

Exception occurs at Activator.CreatInstance(type);

Comment: I'd check if "deserialized" assembly and original one are the same. If I have to guess from error message it seems to be corrupted (assuming DLL itself is untouched).

Comment: You should set a breakpoint under the Assembly.Load line and see what is in the local variable `assembly`.

Comment: They appear to be the same. Would obfuscation or a different .NET version cause this issue?

Comment: which dlls are you using? your's own or third party?

Comment: Obfuscated assemblies can indeed be the cause, if it was about the loaded assembly being compiled under a different .NET version you would have received a specific exception about it.

Comment: Third party DLL with my own. #The Dutch Man - the assembly has appropriate information when debugging.

Comment: Could you post the code which generates the error so I can check the .NET framework namespaces?

Comment: "The type initializer for 'iConfServer.NET.iConfServerDotNet' threw an exception." at iConfServer.NET.iConfServerDotNet..ctor(). I can however access enums from a different class.

Comment: Well, this means it does actually loads the assembly but it fails on calling the constructor, so there is something going wrong in the type you are trying to initialize. Thus I need to see how you are invoking/calling the constructor.

Comment: Just wondering if perhaps the same assembly is being loaded multiple times.  Other implementations which I've seen for dynamically loading assemblies from resources put the `Assembly` objects into a dictionary for subsequent `AssemblyResolve` calls. Perhaps that's just an optimization though.

Comment: @kjbartel it shouldn't be needed because AssemblyResolve won't be called twice for same assembly (so more than an optimization it just wastes memory).

Comment: The assembly might be checking its `CodeBase` and since the name has changed be failing.  Perhaps try writing the file out to a temporary location with it's original filename and load it from there with `Assembly.LoadFile`. Could be easily tested though by just renaming the assembly and seeing if you get the same error when using it non-embedded.

Comment: Actually that check might not work as it may also be checking the file size and modified date etc. So make sure that loading the file dynamically works properly (with `Assembly.LoadFile`) and if it does work then try writing it to a temp location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming these statements where correct (note that these where posted by the original posted in the comments underneath the question):

1. *"The type initializer for .. threw an exception." at iConfServer.NET.iConfServerDotNet..ctor()"*
2. *The assembly has appropriate information when debugging*

The problem probably lies in your way of invoking the constructor. I've created a simple testing library to show you how you can do this properly:

First, the testing library:

```
namespace TestLibrary
{
    public class Main
    {
        public string GetString()
        {
             return "Hey, I'm working well!";
        }
    }
 }
```

I've compiled this to an dynamic link library (.DLL) and added it as **reference** to an console application project (also, just for testing).

As a note, I've changed the `Build Action` property of the resource (you can open the property window by right clicking on the resource in the `Solution Explorer` and clicking `Properties`) to `Embedded Resource`.

This is your code (I just changed the first part as I didn't need it, feel free to change it back) to load the library into our running application:

```
        string resourceName = "TestLibrary.dll";
        string resource = Array.Find(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceNames(), element => element.EndsWith(resourceName));
        Assembly assembly;

        using (var stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(resource))
        {
            Byte[] assemblyData = new Byte[stream.Length];
            stream.Read(assemblyData, 0, assemblyData.Length);
            assembly = Assembly.Load(assemblyData);
            stream.Close();
        }
```

Now, to create a new instance of the class we need to find the type of the class first:

```
       Type _typeOfClass = assembly.GetModule("TestLibrary.dll").GetType("TestLibrary.Main");
```

`_typeOfClass` will now contain the Type that leads us to The `Main` class inside the library.
Next we are going to create a new instance of the class and we are going to invoke the `GetString` method to see if it actually worked:

```
         // Create an instance of the class invoking the (only) constructor. 
        object _instance = _typeOfClass.GetConstructors()[0].Invoke(null);
        // Call the method on the instance we just instantiated
        object result = _typeOfClass.GetMethod("GetString").Invoke(_instance, null);
        Console.WriteLine(result);
```

The Console will now show: *Hey, I'm Working well!*.

If you have multiple constructors and you just want to get the default constructor (no parameters) you can use `object _instance = Activator.CreateInstance(_typeOfClass);` too.

Comment: He wrote: _I receive a TypeInitilizationException with an inner message saying "Assembly has been tampered"_

Comment: Ah, you're right, I forgot about that while writing this answer, it doesn't really matter anyway, he added the code he uses to call the constructor and that is where the problem rises. I'll remove the last part, thanks!

Comment: GetContructors()[0].Invoke(null) still causes the exception with a message "assembly has been tampered".

Comment: Activator.CreateInstance still gives me the weird exception.

Comment: Then your didn't do it the way I described it to you above.. Could you  again post the code you are using to; get the type of the class, the constructor and the invoking of the constructor?

Comment: I guess you have checked the `_type` variable and made sure its the right type? Could you create a simple library and check if you can load up that library without any errors? I'm starting to think there is something wrong with the library you are trying to load..

Comment: Also, have you renamed the DLL from its original name?

Comment: It has not been renamed.

Comment: I can load another DLL just fine. Tested with Microsoft.Kinect.dll

Comment: Okay, then you should do the following; Open your .DLL into a `.NET disassembler`, just Google it and you will find ones you can use. A disaaembler will convert the file back to .NET code (like C#), this way we can find out why it crashes. Once loaded browse to the constructor you are invoking on and you will have to investigate the code and see where it is going wrong. At this point there isn't much we can do here because we don't have the actual DLL/project.

Comment: That was it, the static constructor is being called into is spitting a SecurityException because it's looking for the assembly name as a file but I've embedded it. Now I have to figure out how to bypass this thrown exception so that the non static constructor is called after the static.

Comment: @bl4kh4k I said in the comments to the question that that was most likely the cause of the problem.  Write the dll out to a temp folder and load it from there.  I don't understand why this is the accepted answer or how users who read this question will see this as the correct answer without looking through all these comments.